# How to get the last string after seperated by comms in java?

Tags: java

I have strings separated by comma and need split by comma and need the last value only.I've tried to separated values but i want to help to get the only last string after comma.

My expectation is :

- case 1 : if String is "stack", then I need only stack
- case 2 : if String is "stack,over", then I need only over
- case 3 : if String is "stack,over,flow", then I need only flow.

The same scenario for unlimited strings.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String as[])
    {
    String data = "1,Diego Maradona,Footballer,Argentina";
        String[] items = data.split(",");
        for (String item : items)
        {
            System.out.println("item = " + item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you're asking how to find the last item in an array? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly get the String at the last index.

```
String[] items = data.split(",");
String lastString = items[items.length - 1]; // String at the last index
```

Or you can also use the [`String#substring(beginIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) and the [`String#lastIndexOf(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) methods to get it without splitting the String. Something like this

```
String lastString = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
// +1 because you need to get the string after the last comma
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.substring(data.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
```

or

```
items[items.length - 1];
```

Comment: Note that you can use the char `','` instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  String lastItem = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
  System.out.println(lastItem);
```

Comment: This will give the output as expected in the question. Like if data="stack" output will be stack. If data="stack,over" output will be over.

Comment: @b__ Frankly this is so simple that it don't need any explanation at all

Comment: @Alex : [*"Code-only answers fall under "Very Low Quality" for me and are candidates for deletion"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/185667)

Comment: @b__ I can understand that, but for some real questions. Here this is just String handling 101. But okay.